# C# How Can I Access A Com+ Components ConstructorString

Tags: c#, asp.net, com

Currently I'm using COMAdmin to access the Constructor String which is stored in a specific Applications Com component,

i have looked at some Documentation into System.EnterpriseServices but wasn't sure if there was another and quicker method.

Thank You

Comment: e.g. Private Sub IObjectConstruct_Construct(ByVal pCtorObj As Object)
    Dim ConstructString As IObjectConstructString
    ConstructString = pCtorObj
    msConstructorString = ConstructString.ConstructString
    ConstructString = Nothing
End Sub but in c#

Comment: or http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271284 but in c#